# Как удалить нужную часть текста из текстового документа?

Tags: c++, файлы

Допустим, я записал некоторую структуру в текстовый файл с помощью fwrite, например, 20 заводов. Как я могу удалить нужные мне заводы? Можно ли стереть нужный участок текстового документа?

Comment: Читать, пропуская ненужные элементы, нужные записывать во временный файл. После окончания операции переименовать временный в целевой.

Comment: Если fwrite и участки одинаковой длинны - можете затереть нулями. fseek, fwrite, fseek(to_end). Если разной длинны - тоже можно, но сложнее тогда с занятым и свободным местом - нужен "диспечер памяти"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто "стереть" участок файла невозможно. Его можно перезаписать какой-то иной информацией, и не более того. Можно в принципе обрезать файл, начиная с определенного места, теряя всю информацию.

Обычно при наличии каких-то записей их можно пометить как удаленные, т.е. ваша программа, прочтя, будет понимать, что эта запись не должна учитываться, и переходить к другой. Когда таких записей накопится много - можно просто перезаписать файл с самого начала, оставляя в нем только актуальные записи. Это же можно делать и при каждом удалении, но может оказаться дороговатой операцией.

Можно - если все записи одного размера, а порядок неважен - перезаписывать их информацией из конца файла с последующей обрезкой.

Для текстовых файлов это все достаточно трудно реализовать, но тут у вас противоречие - в заголовке речь о текстовых файлах, в тексте вопроса - о структурах и `fwrite`, т.е. вроде бы о файле бинарном?

Comment: Да, забыл упомянуть, речь шла всё-таки о бинарном файле. Решил что буду перезаписывать каждый раз, ведь в моём случае важно что-бы просто работало. :)